# JPA: Retrieve autogenerated keys after INSERT or UPDATE using em.createNativeQuery

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

Is there any standard way to retrieve the auto-generated column values after issuing an INSERT/UPDATE query using EntityManger's createNativeQuery method?

I'm using EclipseLink 2.6.5 against Oracle DB 11.2 and the latest oracle JDBC drivers.

Comment: Have not tried it but can you check if saved object has an id after persist method is called?
i.e.
       Employee employee  = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName(fName);
        employee.setLastName(lName);
        em.persist(employee);
//employee here should have an id

Comment: why would you use JPA if you are going to ignore its persist mechanism and instead just do random INSERT/UPDATE statements via SQL? That is what JDBC is for

Comment: I want to update a column with the server's time and get that generated time in one pass.

Comment: unless you're going to post your JPA entity with details of precisely what you're trying to do, the answer will be "get the JDBC connection and do the INSERT/UPDATE plus getGeneratedKeys yourself"

Comment: In order to be transactionally consistent I want the entity manager to 'know' about the operation. Excuse me if I'm not sharing any details in deep but I don't think that is relevant. What I'm asking is if a feature is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you need the autogenerated id after an `INSERT` trought native query.
The easy one solution is useing `q.getSingleResults()`

This code may help you:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(insertSql);
BigInteger id = (BigInteger) q.getSingleResult();
long id = id.longValue();
```

In general entity, after persist/merge/native query etc. are available after a commit of the transaction. EJBs, Spring JPA Repository and Hibernate manage the transaction automatically, in any case you have to be sure that transaction commit is already done.

Comment: There could be several auto-generated columns not only the id. For example time columns set with the server time or just an ordinary column set by the server.